# How to link the issues in Bitbucket?

Tags: bitbucket

How to link the issues in Bitbucket?

I already use the `milestone`, `component` and `version` fields, but i need to mark issue as `depend on #125` or `blocked by #1220`.

How?

**Update**

I can place `link #1` in issue comment, of course, but:

1. Comments are scattered throughout the whole issue log.
2. Linked issue doesn't knowing about it.

So, I've search for `linked issues\tickets` fields, like Bugzilla/Mantis/OTRS do. Or `Linked` and `Related` in Stackoverflow itself.

Comment: Have you tried the help pages on Bitbucket? StackOverflow isn't for software support.

Comment: BitBucket say `buy Jira!`

Comment: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-the-issue-tracker-221449750.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATED

Simply use the # and BitBucket will link automatically to the issue, as you know.

The linked issue isn't aware it was linked (as on GitHub, for example): it's the BitBucket behavior.